# Is it "expectations of X" or "expectations for X"?

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following is correct if I want to ask someone what they expect from their new job:

1. What are your expectations of this job?
2. What are your expectations for this job?

If both are correct, what is the difference between them? I have checked Cambridge dictionaries and Merriam-Webster, but they weren't much help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that both:

> (1) What are your expectations of this job?
>
> (2) What are your expectations for this job?

are grammatically valid, quite natural, and appropriate for the situation described in the question. Their meanings are not quite identical. Sentence (1) seems to focus more on what the job will provide for the listener, while sentence (2) seems to focus on what the listener expects to do in the job. But this distinction is a subtle nuance, and a fluent speaker might well choose either without giving the choice much thought. The two are close to interchangeable.

> (3) What are your expectations from this job?

suggested by user Yash Laddha, I would think a bit less natural, although quite valid. Probably this is as much a matter of style as anything, somehow "expectations from" does not sit well with me, although I cannot specify any rule that it violates. I certainly would not agree that (1) and (2) are not "correct".

Of the other choices suggested, "expectations regarding" seems a bit stiff to me, but some fluent speakers would use this or a similar phrase. "expectations about" carries much the same meaning as "expectations of", but a bit more general and all encompassing. In my view there is nothing at all wrong with it, and it is quite natural.

Answer (score 1):

What are your expectations regarding this job? Formal

What are your expectations about this job? Informal

to have expectations about something.

Answer (score 1):

In formal or informal conversation in the UK, both would be acceptable. Most people are not aware of the correct grammar and won't notice which you have used. However, if you want to be grammatically correct...

'Expectations of' concerns something that has already happened or something that is guaranteed or planned to happen. For example "I had high expectations of the opera" or "My expectations of the play I am attending tonight are very high"

'Expectations for' concerns something that 'might' happen in the future or something that is hoped for, for example 'My expectations for the economy are pessimistic", "My expectations for the horse to win the next race are very high"

'Expectations from' applies grammatically if the expectations have been given to us by another person or thing, for example "My expectation from my father is that getting old is tiresome" or "My expectations from last year's show means I am very excited about this year's event."

Your question concerning someone's new job would come under the first definition if they already had the job and so the correct use would be "What are your expectations of this job?". If they did not have the job but were hoping to get it, the correct grammar would be "What are your expectations for this job?"

If someone were to answer that question, the correct grammar would be 'expectations for' as they do not yet know how the job will go. "My expectation for this job is it will be very rewarding but challenging".

It is important to repeat though that in a real conversation, most people would not mind ( or even notice) which was used.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough answer! It's a pity only one answer can be chosen as the one that truly answered the question, or I would have checked your answer besides David Siegel's :)

Comment: When stating such a fine distinction as a "rule" or as correct" vs "not correct" I am alsways happier if the answer cites a reliable source.

Answer (score 0):

Neither, in my opinion is correct in this context.

The correct phrasing would be

> What are your expectations **from** this job?

You have even used it correctly while asking the question "Which of the following is correct if I want to ask someone **what they expect from their new job:**"

Comment: Interesting! I wonder what you base this answer on? :)